# Can you be drunk by drinking too much alcosynth?

Tags: alcohol

In [Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/health-and-families/health-news/hangover-free-alcohol-david-nutt-alcosynth-nhs-postive-effects-benzodiazepine-guy-bentley-a7324076.html) article we can read about alcosynth which is a substitute to alcohol by mimicking the same effects, but without having the bad effects.

Few highlights:

- > The new drink, known as 'alcosynth', is designed to mimic the positive effects of alcohol but doesn’t cause a dry mouth, nausea and a throbbing head
- > And by not touching the bad areas, we don't have the bad effects.
- > in theory it would be impossible to ever feel too 'drunk'

It says in theory you cannot be drunk. What does it mean in practical sense? Can you really drink as much as you want without the bad effects?

Comment: Looks like the product isn't even released yet, and the researcher has patented 90 different chemicals which he claims to have these effects. Without knowledge of what the chemical even is, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: I don't think it says that you will not get drunk, it says you will not get a hangover. The 'positive effects of alcohol' does include not being able to drive a car, but it is the need for bacon the next morning that is reduced.